# Forest : Draw \hdots between leaves

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

In the following tree, I would like to draw \hdots between pairs of leaves, e.g. between 8-9, 10-11, 12-13, 14-15.
I did not find anything in the manual of the forrest package. I need something similar to

```
\node at ($(9)!.5!(10)$) {\Huge $\hdots$};
```

but I do not know how to reference my forrest nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes circle, draw, 
     semithick,
    minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree
    l sep =12mm,
    s sep = 6mm,
%    draw=cyan!60,
/tikz/arr/.style = { -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}, shorten >=1pt},
% for the case when you like to have
% all edges to bottom nodes dashed; 
% using this, remove next code line with edge = arr,
%if level = 1{edge=arr}{edge={arr, dashed}}, 
     edge = arr,
        },
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.5, node
              font=\footnotesize, text=blue, anchor=#1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
%%%% diagram body
[, phantom, s sep = 1cm
    [1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$, tier=0
        [2, EL=1-p
            [4, EL=1-p
                [8, edge=dashed]
                [9, edge=dashed]
            ]
            [5, EL=p
                [10,edge=dashed]
                [11, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
        [3, EL=p
            [6, EL=1-p
                [12, edge=dashed]
                [13, edge=dashed]
            ]
            [7, EL=p
                [14, edge=dashed]
                [15, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$t=0$}
        [{$t=1$}
            [{$t=2$}
                [{$t=T$}, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `,name=foo` into your node brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes circle, draw, 
     semithick,
    minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree
    l sep =12mm,
    s sep = 6mm,
%    draw=cyan!60,
/tikz/arr/.style = { -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}, shorten >=1pt},
% for the case when you like to have
% all edges to bottom nodes dashed; 
% using this, remove next code line with edge = arr,
%if level = 1{edge=arr}{edge={arr, dashed}}, 
     edge = arr,
        },
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.5, node
              font=\footnotesize, text=blue, anchor=#1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
%%%% diagram body
[, phantom, s sep = 1cm
    [1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$, tier=0
        [2, EL=1-p
            [4, EL=1-p
                [8, edge=dashed, name=B1]
                [9, edge=dashed, name=B2]
            ]
            [5, EL=p
                [10,edge=dashed]
                [11, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
        [3, EL=p
            [6, EL=1-p
                [12, edge=dashed]
                [13, edge=dashed]
            ]
            [7, EL=p
                [14, edge=dashed]
                [15, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$t=0$}
        [{$t=1$}
            [{$t=2$}
                [{$t=T$}, edge=dashed]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[dotted,red] (B1) -- (B2);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: naming nodes in forest]

If you want `\hdots` between your nodes, replace the `draw` command by `\path (B1) -- (B2) node[midway]{\dots};`

[image: with dots]